# Tensorflow r1.4 estimator save/load

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to LOAD a previously saved Tensor DNNRegressor to predict from new data to verify the saving/loading process using the estimator classes API r1.4. The problem could be either in how I am using the loader or how I am saving the model. The data is from a csv for real numbers for training with a future unknown input size so I have not used keys in the feature_columns

## Training

```
train_inputs =numpy.float32(dftrain.values)
train_outputs =numpy.float32(dftest.values)

feature_columns=[tf.feature_column.numeric_column("XX", shape=[103])]

estimator=tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns, hidden_units=[20])

input_fn_train = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"XX": numpy.array(train_inputs)}, y=numpy.array(train_outputs),
    batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=None, shuffle=False)

estimator.train(input_fn_train, steps=num_steps)
```

## Saving

```
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)

export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)

export_dir = estimator.export_savedmodel(output_directory, export_input_fn)
```

## Loading and new Prediction

```
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(load_folder)
train_X =numpy.float32(dftrain.values)
```

Predict just first row

```
traininput=train_X[0]

predict_input_fn_test = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
x={"XX": numpy.array(traininput)},
num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)

predictions = predict_fn(predict_input_fn_test)
```

giving error

input_keys = set(input_dict.keys())
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: #Solved                                                                                  model_input= tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'x': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=traininput))        
    })) 

model_input=model_input.SerializeToString()

predictions = predict_fn({"inputs":[model_input]})